# Display .obj in Android using Rajawali not working

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, 3dsmax, rajawali

I want to display a 3d object in an android application using the Rajawali framework. I created a 3d object with Autodesk 3DS MAX. (I`ve read articles that it is recommended to use blender. But I downloaded a model which I wanna use and its a .3ds file)

I put the .obj and .mtl in the raw folder (renamed the files as recommended in mymodel_obj and mymodel_mtl), then I created a Renderer class:

```
public class Renderer extends RajawaliRenderer {

private Context context;
private Object3D mObject;


//constructor
public Renderer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setFrameRate(60);
}

@Override
protected void initScene() {
    try {
        LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(context.getResources(),mTextureManager, R.raw.denture_obj);
        objParser.parse();
        mObject = objParser.getParsedObject();       
        getCurrentScene().addChild(mObject);  
    }catch (ParsingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {}
}
```

I want to display the model in a fragment. This is the Fragment:

```
public class VisualizationFragment extends Fragment {

private IRajawaliSurface surface;
private Renderer mRenderer;
private final static String TAG = "VFRAG";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.visualization_frag, container, false);
    mRenderer = new Renderer(getActivity());
    applyRenderer(v);
    return v;
}

protected void applyRenderer(View v) {
    surface = (IRajawaliSurface) v.findViewById(R.id.brush_surface);
    surface.setSurfaceRenderer(mRenderer);
}
}
```

When I start my application I just getting a black background without any model and following errors:

```
 11-25 20:33:19.677 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.678 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.683 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.683 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.686 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.686 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.689 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
 11-25 20:33:19.689 3187-3201/com.example.marti.ibrush E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
```

I also tried to export my model in the 3ds format, then imported it in blender and exported again in .obj. But it doesn't work, as well. 
I have paid attention to the following export regulations:
https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-17-Importing-.Obj-Files
But I cannot find the "Include Normals" option in blender, so I chose "Write Normals".

Answer (score 0):

On your code, I think you need add Light and Camera under the `initScene()`

On Blender, before export, I would suggest to make sure the underlying texture image file name is in small cap. 
When export, please make select the 'Strip Path' option.

Remember to copy the texture image file to res\drawable folder under your app project.